# Was trying to do a fresh install of 16.04LTS and got into issues

Tags: boot, 16.04

I already have Windows 10 and Ubuntu Linux Desktop 14.04 LTS working fine. Later I added another driver and was not able to use the LVM to use the reminder of the second drive for Ubuntu.
That's why i thought it's better to install Ubuntu 16.04 over 14.04
After getting the right .iso file and using it...i tried doing that and selected something else...was not able to figure out how to use the LVM at the install time...i tried to quit the install....fortunately i have the rescue disks for Windows and made the backup also....but after quitting the linux installation in between....i am stuck with the grub rescue screen.

```
Minimal BASH like line editing is supported. for the first word, TAB lists possible        command completions. anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
```

And I click Tab and show this:

```
Possible commads are: [authenticate badram boot break clear configfile continue cutmem echo export extract_entries_configfile extract_entries source gettext initrd insmod linux loopback is menuentry normal normal_exit probe return search search.File search.fs_label search.fs_uuid set setparams shift source submenu terminal_input terminal_output test unset.
```

Somewhat like that...
this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) and this [one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1599293) are not working for me....

I had /dev/sda7 as my '/' and /dec/sda6 as swap while /dev/sda2 was /boot/efi and /dev/sdb3 as LVM2 PV...

At the grub rescue i can figure out where my '/' is

```
ls (hd0,gpt7)/
```

shows

```
boot/
etc/
opt/
mnt/
root/
usr/
var/
```

etc...

What to do? Please help.

Tried these solutions
[#1](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows)
[#2](http://www.kapilarya.com/fix-windows-10-master-boot-record-corrupted)

but no success...i am getting the desired results(as per those  blogs)but still i am getting to the grub rescue mode only...there is no way

Even after trying these commands from Windows command prompt(after using recovery media and troubleshooting)

```
BOOTREC /SCANOS
BOOTREC /FIXMBR
BOOTREC /FIXBOOT
BOOTREC /REBUILDBCD
bootsect /nt60 SYS or bootsect /nt60 ALL
```

No impact...i am just stuck with the grub rescue mode.
Can't find any .iso in the USB media to follow the other link.

**Update**

Tried using Windows 10 recovery media(USB) and reset the computer to it's factory mode also...set secureBoot to disabled, legacy boot support to enabled and fast boot disabled...stuck with the grub command line menu only...
(hd0,gpt7) contains my root(/) and other partitions for ubuntu Linux...but sudo mount etc...doesn't work...can't even wipe Ubuntu and get it to Windows 10(was planning to install Ubuntu Linux desktop 16.04)

Posted the issue to microsoft community [also](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/dual-boot-with-linux-on-my-windows-10-but-now-in/b2bf09fb-d7e7-451c-bf8c-eea8b1431eff?tm=1462242664678).

Want to completely remove Ubuntu 14.04 and re-install(recover) Windows 10 using the recovery media. Once Windows 10 is installed then i would like to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

**Update**
Right now getting this error...i am using the recovery USB driver from Windows 10 only...it should work...but not working...how i can completely wipe out my entire hard driver contents and make sure that Windows recovery drive is recovering my PC...i am ready to loose data if need to be.

Now Windows 10 recovery is also not happening. I am stuck at this screen for ever.

Somehow used the Ubuntu Live USB(16.06 LTS)...try ubuntu and this is how it looks like in gparted.

and this is the pastebin [contents](http://paste2.org/N8FPzpN9)

**Update(5/5/2016)**

Even [os-uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) is of no help in my case.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a lot of followups I was able to get the original installation media for Windows 10 from Costco Concierges(as they were covering the desktop for the 2nd year)..almost 2 weeks plus of efforts....have to wipe everything and reinstall Windows 10 and then trying to install Ubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS alongside.

With new install media...it seems Microsoft tracks the license based on the MAC address of the computer...so it worked for me at least.